# How to create objects that behave like native objects

Tags: javascript

I am new to JS and fully excited about its capability to behave both as a functional & OO language.

I want to create an object Eg: MyString which behaves like the native String() constructor function.

When I call `String('name')` on the chrome console, I get 'name'.
When I call `var s = new String('sname');` I get an object instance.

Similarly I tried doing the same

```
function MyString(val){
     this.toString1 = function(){ return " " + val; }
     return val;
}
```

When I call `MyString('name')`, I get 'name'
When I call `var ms = new MyString('sname');` I get an object which exposes a toString1() method (just like the native String()'s toString())

My question is:
The MyString constructor function polluted the parent/global scope with a new method toString1() when called like this `MyString('name')`. I dont want this to happen. How do I create objects like the native?

Comment: It seems to me as invalid Q with invalid As. You are playing around the use or the lack of use of the `new` operator before function calls. They have quite different result.

Comment: I was looking for something like a replica of Native type (String(), Number()..etc) They can be used without `new`

Comment: In JavaScript, every function (well, in JS everything is an object) can be used with or without `new`. The result is different. With `new`, the function acts as a constructor and an instance of its type is created. Without `new`, it's just executed procedurally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if your constructor is called with new very easily:

```
function MyString(val) {
  if (this instanceof MyString) { // called with new
    this.toString1 = function(){ return " " + val; }
    this.name = 'My name is ' + val;
  } else { // called without new
    return '' + val;
  }
}
```

Usually it's a good idea to set methods common to all your instances on the prototype, but i assume that was not the point of your question.

```
MyString.prototype.getMyName = function(){ return this.name; }
```

Comment: yes, the prototypal way. But whats the difference? 
hicurin and dystroy answers prototypal.

Comment: @2ndlife There are two differences: 1) there exists only one getMyName function and there is one toString1 function for each instance of MyString. 2) toString1 has access to the private val variable(parameter actually) in the constructor, while methods defined on the prototype have no way to access variables defined in the constructor. Obviously the first is an advantage of prototype-defined methods and the second a limitation.

Comment: I think this is correct. I am trying to find more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should use [prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype) :

```
function MyString(val){
     this.val = val;
}
MyString.prototype.toString1 = function(){ return " " + this.val }
var s = new MyString("thing");
console.log(s.toString1()); // logs " thing"
```

The `toString1` isn't attached to the external scope. It's automatically accessible on all instances of `MyString`. The fact it's attached to the prototype and not to the object avoid the duplication of the function, making it more efficient.

If what you want is to avoid the `MyString` constructor to pollute the external scope when improperly called without the `new` operator, the answer, while it's easy, is **Don't** : Don't protect against flagrantly improper use of your API because it makes your code complex without gain. It's a lost fight anyway, bad coders will always find a way to fail using your code. Using `new SomeClass(args)` is basic JavaScript programming.

Comment: Whats the correct/effecient way to do this? without or with prototype?

Comment: Use the prototype if you want a "class". That's the proper efficient way. But try not to abuse OOP : JavaScript is much less verbose when you use more functional programming than OOP. Don't create useless classes.

Comment: `val` polluted the parent scope.

Comment: @2ndlife Did you use `new` ? If so, it **doesn't** pollute the parent scope.

Comment: No, but that's my question in the first place. I must be able to use with and without `new` and not pollute scope. Thats how natives like String() or Number() work. Isn't it?

Comment: Those are old classes, which wouldn't be designed like this today. Most native classes don't behave this way. And other behave in very confusing way (compare `Date()` and `new Date()` : the first one returns a string). You shouldn't try to make your class usable for people who forget to use `new`. In any case, @tibos' answer on how to do it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
MyString = function(name){ this.name = name; }
MyString.prototype.toString = function(){ return " " + this.name; }
```

Comment: Do you really want to replace the native String class ?